# Import all but last three rows of CSV file into SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CSV file that is created by another process (that I can't change) which includes a time stamp and user name in a line below the data. I need to import the data without the final line, because it causes an error due it being an invalid column value.

If I manually remove this line (which I want to avoid doing), my SQL can successfully import the data using:

```
BULK INSERT #TempReport
FROM 'D:\ac2000\Reg.csv'
WITH
(
FORMAT = 'CSV', 
FIRSTROW = 2, -- second row so skip header row in csv file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
FIELDQUOTE = '"', -- Double quote mark is a text delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

I know that there is also a LASTROW option in Bulk Insert, but the CVS will have a different number of rows each time, so I need a way to calculate the number of rows, without importing it! ... or at least, not importing it with the method above, which only results in another error.

Comment: Why not just import all rows and delete the last 3 rows from the temp table?

Comment: @PeterHe That's just it - the import will not work in the first place because of the timestamp in the last line, which causes the error as it is an invalid column value.

Comment: I usually import the entire file into a table with a 'rownumber' column (an `identity`) and a `varchar(8000)` and then clean it up from there - delete last rows, split out fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **READ** the csv file without import it.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK N'd:\temp\data.csv',
    FORMATFILE = 'D:\temp\fmt.fmt',
    FIRSTROW=2
) j
```

### For example

**data.csv**

```
ID, User
1,User1
10,User 10
11,User 11
2,user2
```

**Format File**

```
13.0
2
1       SQLCHAR 0       2       ","         1     PersonID               ""
2       SQLCHAR 0       25      "\r\n"      2     FirstName              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

You can use a `.fmt` or `.xml` and generate it using `bcp`.

You can read more on format file and how to generate it following links below.
[NON xml format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/relational-databases/import-export/non-xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)
[XML format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)
[Generate format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

And here documentation about [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)